# Why does the noun "assumption" lose the "p" when it goes to verb form: "assume?"

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology

Nouns such as "consumption," "assumption," and "presumption" all have the letter "p" but their verb forms, "consume," "assume," and "presume" do not.

Why is that? Is there a simple linguistics reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is simply that the stems of these verbs (which come from Latin) did not have a /p/ sound. The [p] was inserted before /t/ in Latin for much the same reasons that English speakers tend to insert a [p] between /m/ and /t/ in words like "dreamt" (from the stem "dream", not *"dreamp").

Latin spelling is for the most part phonetic, so in Latin the insertion of the sound [p] could be indicated in writing by the addition of the letter "p". (It wasn't always: "mt" and "mpt" cooexisted as variant spellings in Latin. But the "mpt" spellings came to be established in English.)

Since there is no "t" in *consume, assume* and *presume* (or their Latin sources), there is no "p" either.